# How can I get a visual representation of AWS infrastructure being built on an account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Are there any ways to get a visual representation of the AWS resources, egress, ingress, etc from either Terraform scaffold code or from the AWS console?

Currently the only option I have is slowly picking through it all and drawing it out to get a visual.

Answer (score 0):

There are third-party tools that can query your infrastructure and draw diagrams, such as:

- [Hava | Automated AWS Architecture Diagrams](https://www.hava.io/)
- [Automatic Diagram to Visualize AWS Cloud Infrastructure | Hyperglance](https://www.hyperglance.com/aws/)
- Or, just [search for them](https://www.google.com/search?q=visualize+aws+infrastructure)